# NPM Module, ES6, require vs import, sharing code, lib creation etc

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, shared-libraries, babeljs

So I'm looking for guidance, I reckon I got myself confused with all this. I know my answer is somewhere on the internet, and I might have actually read it, but I'm just confused with all this.

What I'm trying to achieve: I was coding ReactJS and React Native apps on the same topic, and I had to copy paste code from one to the other, I thought: enough, I haven't copy pasted code in years, let's make a lib. I didn't get anywhere so I thought: enough, let's make a stupid test so I understand it and take it from there. Still got nowhere (I'm awesome aye? :D).

Anyway so here is what I came up with:

```
testLib/
  app/
    hw.js
  lib/
    hello.js
```

With this I made hello.js look like this:

```
exports.world = function() {
    return "Hello World 1";
};
```

An ***npm link*** in lib, an ***npm link hello*** in app, and hw.js:

```
var hello = require("hello");

console.log(hello.world());
```

***node hw.js*** shows "Hello World 1" I'm king of the world. So at this point I understand how to make a javascript library which I can probably use for standard websites. Maybe? I guess there's more to it, but that's the idea.

Now: import XX from YY is ES6 if I understand that well, so I can either use experimental stuff and rename everything to mjs (what kind of a solution is this really? :)) or use webpack, I'm familiar with webpack so here is how I updated lib:

```
testLib/
  lib/
    dist/
      bundle.js
    src/
      index.js
  webpack.config.js
```

the webpack config is simple as:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        bundle: __dirname + "/src/index.js",
    },
    devtool: "",
    output: {
        path: __dirname + "/dist",
        filename: "[name].js",
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".js"],
    },
    optimization: {
        minimize: false, 
    },
};
```

index.js has a basic:

```
export default {
    world: function() {
        return "Hello World 2";
    },
};
```

But now, I cannot get require to comply, ***require('hello')*** doesn't work anymore, so I gotta go with ***require('hello/dist/bundle')*** which is basically an empty object.

I assumed that require doesn't play along with es6, I updated my app/hw.js to app/hw.mjs (which makes me sad) and run it with *--experimental-modules* but I still can't get to import my lib with either ***import world from 'hello';*** or ***import world from 'hello/dist/bundle'***

I guess I must be missing something obvious here, and any help or pointers would be gratefully received.

Cheers

PS: I've tried installing "@babel/core", "babel-loader" and "babel-preset-env" in the lib, still got nowhere. I also checked a lot of existing libraries, but the lack of standard is a painful realisation and ended up adding even more confusion.

Comment: *"but I still can't get to import my lib"* How do you determine that it doesn't work? *"so I gotta go with require('hello/dist/bundle') which is basically an empty object."* What about `require('hello/dist/bundle').default` ?

Comment: Interesting! so I've tried: var hello = require("hello/dist/bundle").default; and hello is undefined.